# Graph QL Nested Queries

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, strapi

I'm using Apollo/GraphQL + Strapi for a backend API setup – I'm new to this configuration so please forgive the simple question.

I'm trying to make a simple API query using GraphQL but for some reason nesting the queries seems to block data from being returned. In the GraphQL playground (in which everything seems to be working OK in general) if I make the query:

```
query {
  statements {
    id
    description
    keywords {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Then I get:

```
"statements": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "description": "Lorum ipsum dolor est...",
        "keywords": [
          {
            "description": "lorum"
          }
        ]
      },
  ... 
]
```

Which is what I would expect – I get the object with the `description`  within the `keyword` array. However if I then nest that same query for `statements` within a larger query tied to `concepts` with:

```
query {
  concepts {
    id
    Title
    statements {
      id
      description
      keywords {
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following, *without* the data coming through in the nested `keywords` array...

```
"concepts": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "Title": "Lorum Ipsum",
        "statements": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "description": "Lorum ipsum dolor est...",
            "keywords": []
          },
  ...
]
```

I presume this must be a syntax error on my part(?) but I cannot work out how to get this working – it seems like a very basic aspect of the Graph query language.

Comment: Your query is valid, if it wasn't, you'd see errors returned in the response. It's either a bug with strapi or some misconfiguration of it.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRearden – can you think of a bug/misconfig where it would work in one instance and not another? If it wasn't working at all I feel I'd know where to look but it's the inconsistency that has me stumped!